# Max functions not working, it returns min function value

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

max functions not working in my stored procedure it returns the same value with min function but it works in sql editor. my column is int unsigned. here is my code :

these code below work properly but not in my stored procedure.

```
select idPatient from tb_patient where nomPatient='CARRIE' and prenomPatient='Marie Claude' and idPatient>267; -- result 268
select max(idPatient) from tb_patient where nomPatient='CARRIE' and prenomPatient='Marie Claude'; -- result 268
select idPatient from tb_patient where nomPatient='CARRIE' and prenomPatient='Marie Claude'; -- result 267 268

drop procedure if exists findTwins;
delimiter ##
create procedure findTwins()
begin 
    declare getNom varchar(40);
    declare getPrenom varchar(40);
    declare getId int default 1;
    declare getId2 int default 1;
    if(select count(*) from tb_patient group by nomPatient,prenomPatient having count(*)=2 limit 1)
    then
        select nomPatient,prenomPatient into getNom,getPrenom from tb_patient group by nomPatient,prenomPatient having count(*)=2 limit 1; 
        set getId=(select min(idPatient) from tb_patient where nomPatient=getNom and prenomPatient=getPrenom);
        set getId2=(select  max(idPatient) from tb_patient where nomPatient=getNom and prenomPatient=getPrenom);
        select concat(getNom,' ',getPrenom,' ',getId,' ',getId2) as Patient;
    end if; 
end##

call findTwins();
```

the result of this query should be: **CARRIE Marie Claude 267 268**
but I get **CARRIE Marie Claude 267 267**
whatever I do I can't find 268 from my stored procedure even I just run select...where... without min or max function I only get 267. 
table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE tb_patient (
    idPatient INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    nomPatient varchar(40) not null,
    prenomPatient varchar(40) not null,
    emailPatient varchar(40) unique, 
    index ind_patient_name(nomPatient,prenomPatient))
ngine=innoDB;
```

Comment: Why not do it as one query? `SELECT MIN(idPatient) AS minId, MAX(idPatient) AS maxId, nomPatient, prenomPatient FROM tb_patient ...`

Comment: it works now. but i'm fascinated by the reason why  it didn't... cause the syntax is correct. is this a MySQL workbench issue or something else...?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the `mysql` command line client. I get `CARRIE Marie Claude 267 268`. I don't use MySQL Workbench.